# how to use wild card operators from user input to search a text file

Tags: java

I'm new to java but need to know how to get a wildcard operator to work.

What I want is  any user input with wildcard e.g.

> SWE*

- all possible matches from a particulr file will appear on the screen.

In case of mentioned example the words *sweat* and *sweet* should be shown if they exiting in the sourcing file.

Comment: can you share sample code of the place of problem?

Comment: Have you written something to achieve this? If you want to search a word multiple times then it would be too time consuming to read whole file everytime.  I am assuming you are using single file, it is better to write a recursive method that stores value in say hashmap and search for specific key from keyset.

Comment: System.out.println("Please enter search phrase... ");
            String wordname = scan.nextLine();
            int count = 0;
            try  {
                LineNumberReader r = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(path));
                String line; 
                 while ((line =r.readLine()) != null) {
                    for (String element : line.split(" ")) {
                        if (element.equalsIgnoreCase(wordname)) {
                            count++;
                            System.out.println("Word found at line " + r.getLineNumber());
                   }

Comment: @MellyJMellz if you format you comment, add some explanation and a TRY IT ONLINE-link your comment can be promoted to a faboulous answer.